# How to Customize and add Cursor Files to a project?

Tags: c#, wpf, mouse, mouseover

Quick question:

I am on a Wpf application and I use this routine to get my cursor shape changed on mouse hoover over my Image:

```
private void mainGrid_MouseEnter(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    mainImage.Cursor = Cursors.Hand;
}

private void mainGrid_MouseLeave(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    mainImage.Cursor = Cursors.Arrow;
}
```

Output:

[image]

How can I get the below shape instead?

[image]

I wish that this could simply work:

```
foreach (var finger in fingers.Skip(2)) { finger.Extend(); }
```

But no.. Programming does not work like that..

My desired shape is not available in cursors: [Cursors Class](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=system.windows.input.cursors)

Comment: Hahaha, +1 for your last little code snippet! -- But being serious now: You would have to create a custom cursor if you want to use other ones than the predefined. A cursor is only an image (or multiple images, if it's aminated) with some information about its hotspot, etc.

Comment: I could flip off someone the easy way if it works you know @VisualVincent. Build my own customized one.. Is it much code or simple?

Comment: There's pretty much no code. All you need is something to create a cursor file with. You can do that in Visual Studio using the built-in _Image Editor for Icons_, see: [\[ 1 \]](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s1dadd79.aspx) [\[ 2 \]](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cf706c2y.aspx).

Comment: You can just open the `Add New Item` dialog and select a cursor file from there. Then double-click it in the Solution Explorer to edit it. -- I'll post a complete answer when I get access to a computer.

Comment: @VisualVincent okay I see. And I will wait. Thanks :)

Comment: Sorry for the wait, I'm writing my answer now...

Comment: Okay it took _much_ longer than I expected, but I have written a full, but still compact, step-by-step answer about how to create and use your own cursor.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

In order to get a cursor like that you would need to get (or create) a custom one. There's no such cursor built into Windows. Creating your own cursor can be done using Visual Studio's built-in [**Image Editor for Icons**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s1dadd79.aspx).

### Creating your own cursor

1. To start with open the `Add New Item` dialog.

   > [image: Add New Item]

---

2. Then scroll down and select `Cursor File`, give it a name of your choice.

   > [image: Select "Cursor File" in the dialog.]

---

3. It'll now open your new cursor file in the so called *Image Editor for Icons*. Now you can just start drawing using the pencil or any of the other different drawing tools (images can also be pasted, but as you see the cursor initially has the 1 bit color format - meaning there's only two colors: black and white. This can be changed by adding a new image type).

   > [image: Are you reading these descriptions? :)]

---

4. Now we must specify a [**hot spot**](http://www.axialis.com/tutorials/what-is-a-cursor.html#t8) for the cursor. The hot spot is the position in the icon which Windows uses to track where the pointer is actually located (for simplicity you could call it the cursor's click point). The normal Windows 7 Aero Arrow has its hot spot at (0, 0) - the top left corner.

   To specify the cursor's hots pot we must use the `Set Hot Spot Tool`. Then you click at the specific pixel that you want to use as the hot spot in your cursor icon. For this cursor I chose (9, 8).

   > [image: Set Hot Spot Tool]

   **Setting the hot spot at (9, 8):**

   > [image: Setting the actual hot spot]

---

5. Save everything, then go to the `Solution Explorer`, right-click your project and press `Properties`. Then go to the `Resources` tab and click `Add Resource` and `Add Existing File...`.

   Now locate your project's folder and select and open your cursor file.

   > [image: Add a new resource]
   >
   > [image: Select your cursor file]

---

6. The final non-code step is to select your cursor in the `Solution Explorer`, go to the `Properties` pane and set `Build Action` to `None`. This is to prevent it from being added two times to your compiled executable, since it's already added as a resource.

   **IMPORTANT:** Do **NOT** do this for the cursor file located in the `Resources` folder!

   > [image: Set Build Action to None for your cursor.]

---

### Using your custom cursor in your application

Now onto the code, which is rather simple actually. As your cursor is now added as a byte array resource you only have to load that into a `MemoryStream`, then pass that memory stream into the constructor of a `Cursor` class. For simplicity and readability I put this code in another class.

```
public static class CursorHelper
{
    public static Cursor FromByteArray(byte[] array)
    {
        using (MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream(array))
        {
            return new Cursor(memoryStream);
        }
    }
}
```

Now you can just go ahead and declare your cursor at class-level in your form/control/etc. and you'll be ready to use it!

```
private Cursor OpenHand = CursorHelper.FromByteArray(Properties.Resources.CursorOpenHand);

public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    this.Cursor = OpenHand;
}
```

### Example usage

I made an example per your specifications; a normal open hand that changes to a grabbing hand when you hold down your mouse:

```
private Cursor OpenHand = CursorHelper.FromByteArray(Properties.Resources.CursorOpenHand);
private Cursor GrabbingHand = CursorHelper.FromByteArray(Properties.Resources.CursorGrabbingHand);

public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    this.Cursor = OpenHand;
    this.MouseDown += this.MainWindow_MouseDown;
    this.MouseUp += this.MainWindow_MouseUp;
}

private void MainWindow_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    ((Control)sender).Cursor = GrabbingHand;
}

private void MainWindow_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    ((Control)sender).Cursor = OpenHand;
}
```

**Profit!**

> [image: Animation of the custom cursor]

---

Here are the cursors that I used:

- http://www.mydoomsite.com/sourcecodes/HandOpen.cur
- http://www.mydoomsite.com/sourcecodes/HandGrabbing.cur

Comment: Hi, I got a question for you. My customized icons/shapes are transparent. How could I **fill** them white?

Comment: @FirstStep : Make sure the figure is closed and use the fill tool? It looks like a little bucket pouring color. As seen in my pictures it is the dark, blue-green pixels that counts as "transparent".

Comment: Oh maybe because it is opened! But yours here is opened and white inside with black contour at the same time, which I would like to have as well but can't find the colors! Could you guide me please?

Comment: @FirstStep : It's enough if you use the pen to close the figure using the color you want, _then_ use the paint bucket tool. And what do you mean when you say that you cannot find the colors?

Comment: I got it working :) Filled white with black contour. Yes It turned out that _Colors_ are alone on the left side of the designer and not on the top panel, and hidden in my case. Thanks again !

Comment: @FirstStep : The colors can be found in the `Colors` box (on the left of [**this image**](http://i.stack.imgur.com/YL2Vn.png)). But you will only have black and white if you use the 1-bit format. **EDIT:** No problem.

Comment: @FirstStep : If you in the future would want to use normal colors, you would have to add a new image type (the button for that is on the _right_ of the `Set Hot Spot Tool` button), then you'd choose for example `32 x 32, 32 bit` (or whatever it says). `32 bit` (possibly even `24 bit`) means that you can use 16 million different colors, while `1 bit` is just two different colors. It's determined by `2^(bits)`. For example: `2^24 = 16 777 216`.

Comment: I see, this way I can use whatever image I want, as a cursor icon. Awesome! +10 if possible :D

Comment: @FirstStep : As long as that image is 32x32 or smaller, yes ;). - Also, be sure to remove the other image types. Only use one for cursors.

Answer (score 3):

As others have mentioned, you need a custom cursor for this shape.

I'm not particularly proud of this code, but I managed to get myself into a corner and needed to do this in a situation where I couldn't have any new resources in a project, so here's a standalone custom cursor creator for this particular cursor.

You can assign the HandCursor it creates to your form like any other cursor, as an example:

```
public Example()
{
    PictureBox box = new PictureBox();
    box.Bounds = new Rectangle(10, 10, 100, 100);
    box.Cursor = HandCursor;
    box.MouseDown += Box_MouseDown;
    box.MouseUp += Box_MouseUp;
    box.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.Fixed3D;
    Controls.Add(box);
}

void Box_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    ((Control)sender).Cursor = HandCursor;
}

void Box_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    ((Control)sender).Cursor = HandGrabCursor;
}
```

And here's the core of the code:

```
Cursor m_HandCursor = null;
Cursor HandCursor
{
    get
    {
        if (m_HandCursor == null)
        {
            m_HandCursor = CursorFromString(
                "AAACAAEAICAAABAAFACoEAAAFgAAACgAAAAgAAAAQ{A5}EAI{A62}aBgM3GgYD/xoGA/8a" +
                "BgP/GgYD/xoGA/8aBgP/GgYD/xoGA/8aBgO6{A70}GgYDNxoGA73Ny8r/39/f/93d3f/a2" +
                "tr/2NjY/9bW1v/V1dX/09PT/xoGA94{A6a}BoGAzcaBgO909HR/+Xl5f/j4+P/4eHh/97e" +
                "3v/c3Nz/2tra/9jY2P/W1tb/GgYD3hoGAz{A61}aBgM3GgYDvdnX1//s7Oz/6urq/+fn5/" +
                "/l5eX/4+Pj/+Dg4P/e3t7/3Nzc/9ra2v8aBgOHGgYDhw{A5f}BoGA73f3dz/8/Pz//Hx8f" +
                "/u7u7/7Ozs/+np6f/n5+f/5OTk/+Li4v/g4OD/3d3d/7Kurf8aBgPV{A5b}aBgNjGgYDtP" +
                "n5+f/IxMP/9fX1//Ly8v/w8PD/7u7u/+vr6//p6en/5ubm/+Tk5P/i4uL/39/f/xoGA94a" +
                "BgMw{A50}GgYDNhoGA7rm5OT//Pz8/4N5d//4+Pj/9vb2//T09P/y8vL/8PDw/+3t7f/r6" +
                "+v/6Ojo/+bm5v/j4+P/GgYDhxoGA4c{A50}aBgO66Obl{/7}+/v7/GgYD//v7+//6+vr/+" +
                "Pj4//b29v/09PT/8vLy/+/v7//t7e3/6urq/+jo6P+6trX/GgYD1Q{A4f}BoGA//o5uX/6" +
                "Obl/xoGA7oaBgP//v7+//39/f/7+/v/+fn5//j4+P/19fX/8/Pz//Hx8f/v7+//7Ozs/+r" +
                "q6v8aBgP/{A50}GgYDuhoGA/8aBgO6GgYDNhoGA{/d}7+/v/8/Pz/+/v7//n5+f/39/f/9" +
                "fX1//Pz8//x8fH/7u7u/xoGA/8{A65}GgYD{/17}9/f3//Pz8//r6+v/5+fn/GgYD//X19" +
                "f/y8vL/GgYD/w{A65}aBgP{/c}Pysr{/b}8aBgP//f39//z8/P8aBgP/+Pj4//b29v8aBg" +
                "P/{A60}GgYDMDgmJP{/b}4Z7ev{/b}xoGA{/8}v7+/xoGA//7+/v/+vr6/xoGA/8{A60}a" +
                "BgOHhnt6{/c}QC8t{/c}GgYD{/c}GgYD//7+/v/9/f3/GgYD/w{A5f}BoGA9XPysr{/6}8" +
                "/Kyv8aBgP{/b}8aBgP{/b}8aBgP{/6}8/Kyv8aBgO6{A60}GgYD{/c}GgYDhxoGA{/c}xo" +
                "GA{/c}xoGA//Pysr/GgYDuhoGAxo{A60}aBgP{/b}8aBgOHGgYD{/c}GgYD{/7}Pysr/Gg" +
                "YD/xoGA7oaBgMa{A65}BoGA7r{/a}xoGA4caBgP{/b}8aBgP/GgYD/xoGA7oaBgM2{A70}" +
                "GgYDNhoGA7oaBgO6GgYDNhoGA7r{/a}xoGA7o{A95}GgYDNhoGA7oaBgO6GgYDNg{A84a}" +
                "//AD///gA///wAH//4AB//+AAf//AAD//gAA//4AAP/+AAD//gAA///gAP//4AD//8AA//" +
                "/AAP//wAD//8AA///AAf//wAf//8A////8P{/41}8=");
        }

        return m_HandCursor;
    }
}

Cursor m_HandGrabCursor = null;
Cursor HandGrabCursor
{
    get
    {
        if (m_HandGrabCursor == null)
        {
            m_HandGrabCursor = CursorFromString(
                "AAACAAEAICAAABAAFACoEAAAFgAAACgAAAAgAAAAQ{A5}EAI{A62}aBgM3GgYD/xoGA/8a" +
                "BgP/GgYD/xoGA/8aBgP/GgYD/xoGA/8aBgO6{A70}GgYDNxoGA73Pzc3/4eHh/97e3v/b2" +
                "9v/2dnZ/9bW1v/U1NT/0tLS/xoGA94{A6a}BoGAzcaBgO919XV/+rq6v/n5+f/4+Pj/+Dg" +
                "4P/d3d3/29vb/9jY2P/W1tb/GgYD3hoGAz{A61}aBgM3GgYDvd/d3P/y8vL/7+/v/+zs7P" +
                "/p6en/5ubm/+Pj4//g4OD/3d3d/9ra2v8aBgOHGgYDhw{A5f}BoGA73l4+P/+vr6//f39/" +
                "/19fX/8vLy/+/v7//r6+v/6Ojo/+Xl5f/i4uL/39/f/7Ovrv8aBgPV{A5b}aBgNjGgYDtP" +
                "{/5}Nycj/+/v7//n5+f/39/f/9PT0//Hx8f/u7u7/6+vr/+fn5//k5OT/4eHh/xoGA94aB" +
                "gMw{A50}GgYDNhoGA7ro5uX{/6}4Z7ev/+/v7//f39//v7+//5+fn/9vb2//Pz8//w8PD/" +
                "7e3t/+rq6v/n5+f/GgYDhxoGA4c{A50}aBgO66Obl{/c}GgYD{/d}v7+//z8/P/6+vr/+P" +
                "j4//X19f/y8vL/7+/v/+zs7P+9ubj/GgYD1Q{A4f}BoGA//o5uX/6Obl/xoGA7oaBgP{/1" +
                "7}7+/v/8/Pz/+vr6//f39//19fX/8vLy/+/v7/8aBgP/{A50}GgYDuhoGA/8aBgO6GgYDN" +
                "hoGA{/22}9/f3/+/v7//n5+f/39/f/9PT0/xoGA/8{A65}GgYD{/27}+/v7/GgYD//v7+/" +
                "/5+fn/GgYD/w{A65}aBgP{/b}8aBgP{/b}8aBgP{/b}8aBgP//v7+/8zIx/8aBgO6{A65}" +
                "BoGA{/c}xoGA{/c}xoGA{/c}xoGA//Pysr/GgYDuhoGAxo{A65}GgYD/8/Kyv{/6}GgYD{" +
                "/c}GgYD{/7}Pysr/GgYD/xoGA7oaBgMa{A6b}aBgM2GgYDuhoGA/8aBgO6{/a}8aBgO6Gg" +
                "YD/xoGA7oaBgM2{A85}BoGAzYaBgO6GgYDuhoGAzY{Aaf5}//AD///gA///wAH//4AB//+" +
                "AAf//AAD//gAA//4AAP/+AAD//gAA///gAP//4AD//+AA///gAf//4Af///w{/57}8=");
        }

        return m_HandGrabCursor;
    }
}

Cursor CursorFromString(string data)
{
    byte[] bits = Convert.FromBase64String(
                Regex.Replace(data,
                    "\\{(.)([0-9a-f]+)\\}",
                    delegate(Match m)
                    {
                        return new string(
                            m.Groups[1].Value[0],
                            int.Parse(m.Groups[2].Value,
                                System.Globalization.NumberStyles.HexNumber));
                    }
                )
            );

    bits[2] = 1;

    using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(bits))
    {
        return new Cursor(stream);
#if false
        // Version for Windows Forms
        using (Icon icon = new Icon(stream))
        {
            WinAPI.ICONINFO info = new WinAPI.ICONINFO();
            WinAPI.GetIconInfo(icon.Handle, out info);

            info.fIcon = false;
            info.xHotspot = bits[10];
            info.yHotspot = bits[12];

            IntPtr hCursor = WinAPI.CreateIconIndirect(ref info);

            Cursor ret = new Cursor(hCursor);

            return ret;
        }
#endif
    }
}

static class WinAPI
{
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    public static extern bool GetIconInfo(IntPtr hIcon, out ICONINFO piconinfo);
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    public static extern IntPtr CreateIconIndirect(ref ICONINFO piconinfo);

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    public struct ICONINFO
    {
        public bool fIcon;
        public Int32 xHotspot;
        public Int32 yHotspot;
        public IntPtr hbmMask;
        public IntPtr hbmColor;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi I don't mind this copy paste but I will give sometime for other answer. One Q though, I am trying to implement the `MouseDown` and `Up`, so on `Down` my hand is going to change to the "Capturing Hand" and on `Up` to "Released Hand" which is the one in my Q, do you have the string for the "Capturing Hand"?

Comment: Yep, added to the answer.  I'd like to see a better answer too, as I said, this isn't great code, but it did work. :)

Comment: Cool I will give it a shot anyway :) Cool you show its usage? How could readers use it or call it. `mainGrid.Cursor = ??` on Down and Up. Please and thanks

Comment: `WinAPI` Does not exist and Resharper is not suggesting me any libraries. Do you have it? Also `Cursor ret = new Cursor(hCursor);` says can not convert IntPtr to string

Comment: Ahh, sorry, added WinAPI and a quick example.

Comment: Thanks but sorry I edited my previous comment too. See the error at `Cursor ret = new Cursor(hCursor);`?

Comment: And I missed this is WPF, not WinForms, one more edit.

Comment: Anon, you had accidentally put two `using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(bits))` blocks in your code. :)

Answer (score 1):

You can encode a cursor as a base-64 string, and then turn that base-64 string back into a cursor using `Convert.FromBase64String`:

```
byte[] HandGrabCursor = Convert.FromBase64String("AAACAAEAICAAAAkACAAwAQAAFgAAACgAAAAgAAAAQAAAAAEAAQAAAAAAgAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAgAAAAIAAAAAAAAA////AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAD8AAAA/AAAAfwAAAP+AAAH/gAAB/8AAAH/AAAB/wAAA/0AAANsAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////gH///4B///8Af//+AD///AA///wAH//+AB///wAf//4AH//+AD///yT/////////////////////////////8=");

using MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(HandGrabCursor);
Cursor = new Cursor(stream);
```